# Filters for Color blindness in CameraX for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camerax, imagefilter, color-blindness

I am designing an Android application that helps colour blind users by performing image filtering to be able to identify and clarify between different colours in real time. I am implementing the application in Android Studio using Kotlin, using the CameraX library.

However, after much research, I have only found filters that *simulate* colour blindness and not filters that perform colour correction for different types of colour blindness.

Could anyone please direct me towards resources or packages that may help me in this task?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you "clarify between different colours"? Will you argument it with text?

Comment: Ideally I would change colours in CameraX preview itself so that the user will be able to differentiate between the colours in real time.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a tone mapping algorithm. I am not an expert on this topic, but maybe you can revert the color blindness simulation algorithm for this purpose. So for the simulation you have normal tone mapping to color blindness tone. If you can revert this mapping, then there you have your algorithm. If you can point me to the simulation algorithm, I can take a look at it and see if it's possible.